# How to pass params from one npm script into another one

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

Is it possible to run npm script with params from another npm script?

For instance:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ", //should get params here
  "build:dev": "npm run build --env.type=dev"
  "build:prod": "npm run build --env.type=prod"
}
```

So, eventually params such as `--env.type=dev` should be passed to `webpack`.

P.S. I tried with `$@` but with no luck

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_1

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "tt": "node ./t.js",
    "tt:t": "npm run tt -- --env.type=prod"
  }
```

**t.js**

```
'use strict';

console.log(process.argv);
```

**Result**

```
npm run tt 
> node ./t.js

[ '/home/nazar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node',
  '/home/nazar/Workspace/Source/t.js'

npm run tt:t 
> npm run tt -- --env.type=prod
> node ./t.js "--env.type=prod"

[ '/home/nazar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node',
  '/home/nazar/Workspace/Source/t.js',
  '--env.type=prod' ]
```